# WWW class does not work (unity)

Tags: c#, web, unity-game-engine

```
public class Controller : MonoBehaviour {

    // Use this for initialization
    public string url = "http://images.earthcam.com/ec_metros/ourcams/fridays.jpg";
    IEnumerator Start() {
        WWW www = new WWW(url);

        yield return www;

        Debug.Log (www.bytes.Length);
    }
```

WWW class does not work, it returns 0 bytes. What's the problem? This code is the example code of www class in unity docs.

Comment: It works here, the logged byte count is 14211. Does your filename match the classname?

Comment: For me it returns 0. Maybe I'm doing something wrong.. Here's the video. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_6tHHdcGrfI&feature=youtu.be

Comment: I tested it the same way. I'd look at the bytesDownloaded and error fields of the www object next.

Comment: This image is an hotlink error message. It is still a HTTP 200 OK, but I'd suggest testing on some other file on the internet, as this one might be sketchy.

Comment: I tried different urls, but it still returns 0